# 'ORA-21561: OID generation failed for remote Oracle 12c XE Instance - Oracle on Windows 10 client (cx_Oracle using python) on Mac

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to connect to the Oracle instance which is running on Windows 10 through python using cx_Oracle package from a mac machine.
Now while connecting it throw below error.
'ORA-21561: OID generation failed\n'

My Sample code:

```
import cx_Oracle

DSN = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host=server, port=port, service_name=database)
# Below is the DNS
# (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.9)(PORT=50244))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=devXDB)))
con = cx_Oracle.Connection(user, password, DSN)
```

However I am able to connect from same machine (mac) using SQL developer and PyCharm's database browser. I searched across and did not find any solution related to remote instance. The solutions suggested for seems to be working only for the local instances in which one has to edit/update etc/hosts or related file on windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This was indeed the problem of /etc/hosts file issue.
One thing to note here even if the oracle instance is running on a remote machine you client machine's (from where you are connecting to the oracle instance) /etc/hosts file should have the entry like this.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain Amits-iMac.local
```

Replace 'Amits-iMac.local' to your client's hostname.